# Cons of withdrawing money from an Roth IRA account?

Tags: united-states, ira, roth-ira

I would like to withdraw the money from my Roth IRA account. But I have the following concerns, before I make the decision.

1. Will there be fee, charge, or penalty if I withdraw the money from
   Roth IRA?

   Should I try my best to keep the money in Roth IRA till I reach 60, or is there no disadvantage that I withdraw it now?

   Relevant information:

   - I opened the Roth IRA account more than 5 years ago, which was then
     migrated to another brokerage company which acquired my original
     one.
   - I haven't contributed to the Roth IRA account in the last 5 years.
   - the balance in my Roth IRA is less than $4000.
   - I have sold out all the mutual funds I have bought 2 years ago. The money in my Roth IRA has been in "FDIC INSURED DEPOSIT ACCOUNT CORE NOT COVERED BY SIPC" (I didn't put the money in it, so it is a default).
2. Considering tax, when is it better for me to withdraw the money, this year or next
   year?

   Relevant information:

   - I used the money in the account to buy mutual funds. I sold all the mutual funds two years ago, and at that time I had lost 1/4 of the money. The money obtained has been staying the same in the deposit account core since.
     The current balance in Roth IRA is less than the total I have put into, because the mutual funds that I bought didn't perform well, so I think I have net capital loss.
   - I don't have income this year, so my tax this year will be zero. 
     But suppose I will have income next year, so my tax next year will be more than zero.

   Can the capital loss offset tax, so is it better to withdraw it next year than this year?
3. What if it were a traditional IRA account?

Thanks.

Comment: If I don't ask, someone else will: Are you under age 59 1/2?  Have you contributed to this account within the past 5 years?  http://www.obliviousinvestor.com/roth-401k-distribution-rules/

Comment: Yes, I am. The account was created for more than 5 years, and migrated to a different brokerage company 4 years ago because it acquired the original company. I haven't contributed to the account within the past 5 years.

Comment: what does "deposit account core" mean?

Comment: @littleadv: "FDIC INSURED DEPOSIT ACCOUNT CORE NOT COVERED BY SIPC". I didn't put the money in Roth IRA to it, so it is a default.

Comment: Basically it means that your money was lying uninvested during the 5 years of the best returns on the market in a tax sheltered account. Got it. I think you can do whatever you want, the damage you've done already makes anything else pale in comparison.

Comment: @littleadv: After I opened the Roth IRA account more than 5 years ago, I used the money to bought mutual funds.  I sold all the mutual funds two years ago, and at that time I had lost 1/4 of the money. The money obtained has been in the deposit account core since. What do you mean by " the damage you've done already makes anything else pale in comparison"? Will there be fee, charge, penalty, or tax if I withdraw the money from Roth IRA? When shall I withdraw better, this month or next year?

Comment: @Tim what I mean is that you left the money uninvested, or invested poorly, during the period when  you could have made very nice tax-sheltered gains without much efforts. S&P500 was up 16% during the last 2 years (that's including 2015 which was not the best one). It was up 69% in the last 5 years. Whatever fund you invested in that lost money - you had to be really "lucky" to chose exactly that one. Had you left the money in a S&P500 index fund 5 years ago - you'd have now around 8K instead of your 4K (including the 25% you said you lost).

Comment: @littleadv: ok. I was lucky. How about the Roth IRA questions?

Comment: As I said - do whatever you want, you've paid the price already. Not sure I understand exactly what it is you're asking there, but since you've essentially bypassed all the benefits of even having this vehicle - it doesn't really matter what you do at this point.

Comment: Do you have any other IRA money, in a traditional IRA?

Comment: @Joe: no, I don't have a traditional IRA.

Comment: One thing I suggest before doing this is imagine yourself as an old man, and you are asking that old man on a fixed income to give you money for whatever you plan to spend it on. Does it still seem like a good idea? Also, considering the potential earning you may actually be asking for 2-5x the amount you are withdrawing.

Comment: @JohnFx: Thanks. Can you rephrase what you suggest in a more direct way? I don't understand  it.

Comment: @tim The money in your retirement fund is your income for when you are older. By taking money now, you are taking it away from your older self. Make sure it is worth it.

Answer (score 5):

First thing to note is that *contributions* (i.e. the total of all the amounts that you directly contributed into Roth IRA at any point in time) to a Roth IRA can be withdrawn at any time, without needing any reason, without any tax or penalty. Early withdrawal (early because you are under 59.5) of *earnings*, on the other hand, will incur tax and penalty. (I didn't go into withdrawal of conversions as those are a little more complex.)

When you withdraw, contributions come out first, so as long as you don't withdraw more than the amount of past contributions, you won't have any tax or penalty. And if it's not going to have tax, it doesn't really matter if you do it this year or next year. If you need to dip into the earnings, however, then maybe it would be better to do this year so it will be taxed at lower rates.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to mention in my post that the current balance in Roth IRA is less than the total I have put into, because of the mutual funds that I bought, so I think I have net capital loss. I don't have income this year, but may have next year. Can the capital loss   offset tax, so is it better to withdraw it next year than this year? See my update to my post.

Answer (score 4):

One "con" I have not yet seen mentioned: retirement accounts are generally protected from creditors in a bankruptcy.  There are limits and exceptions, Roth has a 1.2 million dollar limit and can be split by a divorce QDRO for instance.  [Link](http://articles.chicagotribune.com/2013-09-20/business/sc-cons-0919-journey-20130920_1_self-directed-ira-retirement-age-retirement-money)

Since it seems you have no income this year, you may may be raiding your IRA for living expenses.   If there is a chance you may declare bankruptcy in the next year or so, consider doing that first and raid the IRA for seed money after.

Answer (score 3):

In a year with no income, the best advice is to convert existing IRA money to Roth. This lets you take advantage of the 'zero' bracket, the combination of your exemption and standard deduction. This adds to $10,300 for a single person.

Other than that, if you are determined to take the money out, just do it. There would be a 10% penalty of the growth, but the original deposit comes out tax free anyway.

Edit - There's a rule that if you sell your entire Roth account (i.e. all Roth accounts, you can't pick one of a few) and have a loss, you can take that loss. (Per Dilip's comment, this strategy is pretty moot, it's not a loss taken against other income as a stock loss would potentially be))

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to mention in my post that the current balance in Roth IRA is less than the total I have put into, because of the mutual funds that I bought, so I think I have net capital loss. I don't have income this year, but may have next year. Can the capital loss   offset tax, so is it better to withdraw it next year than this year? See my update to my post.

Comment: The net loss when all Roth IRAs have been closed and the total amount taken out is less than the amount contributed is deductible only as Miscellaneous Deduction on Schedule A which is subject to the"only in excess of 2% of AGI" rule and also to the Standard Deduction. In short, you need to have enough _other_ deductions to make the total Itemized Deductions exceed the Standard Deduction, as well as a _large_ loss on the Roth IRA to get above the 2% of AGI bar. If the current balance in the Roth IRA is only $4K or so, I doubt that there would any _explicit_ write-off of the loss.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: suppose my net capital loss is $1000, then to make it deductible, should my AGI be no more than $50000? What is the standard deduction usually?